# Import collections from cloud storage to firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I have two projects A and B. I have data exported from project A's firestore database, to project's A cloud storage bucket and later imported in project's B cloud storage bucket. How can I move data from project's B cloud storage bucket into it's firestore database?

From the official docs I can only find how to [move](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data)([import and export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import)) data to cloud storage buckets but not how to import the data back from cloud storage to firestore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import to `Project B` the exported data of `Project A` you may use the
`gcloud firestore import` [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/import).

More specifically:

1. Be sure to set the target project by using:
   `gcloud config set [Project-B]`
2. Import the data from the source Cloud Storage bucket you used to host the exported data by using the `gcloud firestore import command` with the `outputUrixPrefix`:

   ```
   gcloud firestore import [outputUriPrefix]
   ```

Where `outputUriPrefix` is of the format:

```
gs://[SOURCE-BUCKET]/timestamp-of-export-operation
```

I tried myself the above, by following the documentation you shared about [Moving data between projects.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data#begin_an_import_operation)

Comment: Thanks @tzovourn just realized I wasn't setting the source-bucket name well.